# Ruby on Rails - weird behaviour logic by delayed job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I am doing the delayed_job by tobi and when I run the delayed_job but the fbLikes count is all wrong and it seems to increment each time I add one more company. Not sure wheres the logic wrong. The fbLikes method I tested before and it work(before I changed to delayed_job)
not sure where the "1" come from...

[output]

```
coca-cola
http://www.cocacola.com
Likes: 1  <--- Not sure why the fbLikes is 1 and it increment with second company fbLikes is 2 and so on...
```

.

```
[Worker(host:aname.local pid:1400)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:aname.local pid:1400)] CountJob completed after 0.7893
[Worker(host:aname.local pid:1400)] 1 jobs processed at 1.1885 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

> I am running the delayed_job in Model and trying to run the job of
>   counting the facebook likes

here is my code.
[lib/count_rb.job]

```
require 'net/http'
    class CountJob< Struct.new(:fbid)

def perform 
    uri = URI("http://graph.facebook.com/#{fbid}")
    data = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
    return JSON.parse(data)['likes']
end
end
```

[Company model]

```
before_save :fb_likes
def fb_likes            
    self.fbLikes = Delayed::Job.enqueue(CountJob.new(self.fbId))
end
```

Answer (score 0):

the issue is coming from

```
before_save :fb_likes  
def fb_likes  
  self.fbLikes = Delayed::Job.enqueue(CountJob.new(self.fbId))  
end
```

the enqueue method will not return the results of running the CountJob.  I believe it will return whether the job successfully enqueued or not and when you are saving this to the fb_likes value it will evaluate to 1 when the job is enqueued successfully.

You should be setting fbLikes inside the job that is being run by delayed_job not as a result of the enqueue call.

```
before_save :enqueue_fb_likes  
def fb_likes  
  Delayed::Job.enqueue(CountJob.new(self.fbId))  
end
```

Your perform method in the CountJob class should probably take the model id for you to look up and have access to the fbId and the fbLikes attributes instead of just taking the fbId.

```
class CountJob< Struct.new(:id)

def perform
  company = Company.find(id)
  uri = URI("http://graph.facebook.com/#{company.fbid}")
  data = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
  company.fbLikes = JSON.parse(data)['likes']
  company.save
end
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. It would not be possible for me to find the company id as it has not been saved yet at the moment. So I cant use company.find(id) to specify the search.

Comment: If you have to have the like count before saving then I'm not sure using a background job is the best for you.  Background jobs are meant for handling things which take a long time and are not required to be completed immediately for proper handling of the request/action.

Comment: You could set an initial "pending" value for the fbLikes and save the model then call the count job in an after_save to set the correct value in the background, but that would require handing the pending value in the rest of your code if the job fails for whatever reason or another call comes in for the model before the job completes.  This would be how I would most likely handle this situation, as it would push the possibly long running job to the background and have a graceful failure.